# A word for people who hate others success

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for people who hate other people's success?

Let's say there is the following scenario:
**A** is telling **B** that his success should not be considered an achievement.  **B**'s acknowledgement of his achievement as a success shows how B has nothing left to add. **A** can be said to impose a highly dictatorial behaviour, to deny something that falls outside **A**'s acceptance/hate of **B**'s success.

- What single word can define **A**'s behaviour? *Hater* is just too generic.

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence, and perhaps explain why words like *jealous* don't work?

Comment: Do you want an adjective that *describes* such people or a noun that *means* such people?

Comment: "Resentful" is closer than "envious", "covetful" or "jealous", but don't perfectly fit with the hate feeling.

Comment: Actually, this is a pretty good question. Yes, a noun would be nice. A person whose mission in life is to tell on other people is called a snitch. A person who won't spend an extra penny even on himself/herself is a miser. A person who thinks that not following every rule to the letter is called a pedant or a Pharisee. A person who is habitually envious of others and begrudges them every little thing is called - ?

Comment: The word - used quite commonly in social arenas - I believe that describes this type of person the most is "*hater*. Yes, it's actually a word.

Comment: "Hater" is too general. "Begrudger" and "envier" are closer but hardly in common use.

Comment: @Ricky The thing is, a *hater* doesn't envy someone; they simply hate their success - they are **not** envious. No where in the OP's post does he mention <defined person> being envious. There might be some debate as to whether the popular definition of the word should be used over the dictionary definition, though.

Comment: @LeSunstrike : I understand what you're saying. However, when one says "miser," everyone will immediately understand what kind of person is being discussed. "Hater" could mean anything, not just someone who grudges others their success. A hater can hate someone because that someone is a loser; why not.

Comment: @Nathaniel just edited the question with an example

Comment: @Ricky You're taking 'hater' much too literally if you think it is too general. The way it is used nowadays is exactly for the description the OP gave. It is a bit informal.

Comment: @SouparnoMajumder How is 'hater' too generic for you?

Comment: @Mitch - Of course it is informal. But a hater isn't NECESSARILY someone who grudges people their success. Plus, a person who simply hates people is called a misanthrope. Which is not what the OP has in mind. I think I'll expand on this in my next question.

Comment: @Ricky OK. We disagree then.

Comment: The question is still confusing, but marginally less so than before. If you want to reopen a post, then you need to work at it. We have all had questions closed in the past for being "off topic", me for example, you're not the first, and you won't be the last. Your question really should have a sample sentence, showing how this single-word would work.

Answer (score 1):

***hater*** 

> : (*Slang*) a person that simply cannot be happy for another person's success.
>   So rather than be happy they make a point of exposing a flaw in that
>   person. 
>   Hating, the result of being a hater, is not exactly jealousy. The
>   hater doesn't really want to be the person he or she hates, rather the
>   hater wants to knock someone else down a notch. [Urban
>   Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hater)
>
> : (*Informal, mainly US and Canada*) a grudging or spiteful person, esp. one who
>   disparages others: *Don't let the haters get you down*. [Collins English
>   Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hater)
>
> *I can’t believe she went and told my father about everything just to
>   get me in trouble, what a hater.*
>
> The slang term used here is ***hater***, which refers to someone who
>   is jealous or angry toward another person because of their success. [Literary Devices](http://literarydevices.net/slang/)
>
> The term ***hater*** basically means the person you're referring to is
>   jealous of you. They're "hating" on the way you live, your significant
>   other, job, car, family, etc. Everyone has them. And like they say
>   don't let those haters get you down, keep doing what you're doing.
>   It'll only make them madder and jealous! [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061020221212AAnHBnf&submit=y)

In light of your edit, consider ***begrudging*** along with the expression [***have an evil eye***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FXeNbyhrlooC&pg=PA128&dq=%22have+an+evil+eye%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCGoVChMIwdOJ3s3vyAIVgboUCh0pmgLb#v=onepage&q=%22have%20an%20evil%20eye%22&f=false).

> begrudge: to envy or resent the pleasure or good fortune of (someone):
>   *She begrudged her friend the award*. [Random
>   House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/begrudging)
>
> *The opposite trait of a “good eye” is an “evil eye,” or one that is envious. Such an individual is only concerned with what is good for
>   him and not what is good for others. One who has an “evil eye” is not
>   necessarily jealous of others. Worse than that, he feels miserable
>   when others have occasion to be happy and is begrudging of their
>   success. The trait of an “evil eye” is also the root of another
>   negative characteristic known as “Ungratefulness.”*
>   [Birmingham-Bloomfield Chai
>   Center](http://www.bbchai.org/blog/2015/6/10/rabbi-kin-on-parashat-shalach)

Comment: Your post was 26 seconds after my comment your answer appears - quite timely, if I do say so myself. There's just one thing I think you should add to your post: you should include the actual definition, so that the OP can compare the definition to a more credible source than *Urban Dictionary*.

Comment: Way too general, if you ask me. One can hate others for many reasons, not just envy.

Comment: @LeSunstrike ??? The word - used quite commonly in social arenas - I believe that describes this type of person the most is "hater. Yes, it's actually a word. – Le Sunstrike 29 mins ago

Comment: @Elian I meant no offense Elian. I'm just pointing out how we both were thinking of the same word at around the same time. :)

Comment: @LeSunstrike I mean no offense either. Thing is, you're claiming in your comment to my answer that my post was 26 seconds "after" your comment. Fact is, my answer was posted before. :-)

Comment: @Elian - Group hug! Group hug!

Answer (score 1):

**enviers** <sup>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envier)</sup>

Derivative of *envy* meaning *a feeling of discontented or resentful longing aroused by someone else's possessions, qualities, or luck*. This includes, but is not limited to the success.